# Text that doesn't fit into EditText - scroll it to the left

Tags: android, android-edittext

If I set text to my EditText and the text is bigger, the default behaviour is that the text is scrolled to right. Can I scroll it to left?

Example with EditText 8 characters long and text "Sample text":

Normal behaviour: [ple text]

What I want: [Sample t]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the cursor/caret location to first character of the EditText. You need to use [setSelection](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Selection.html#setSelection%28android.text.Spannable,%20int%29).

```
Selection.setSelection(editText.getText(), 0);
```